# add characters at the beginning of a line in R

Tags: r, string, line

I have a simple line like:

"`667778767643555099889890`"

I would like to insert "\1" to the beginning of this line obtaining a final result:

"`\\1667778767643555099889890`"

What is the command to do it in R?

Comment: you want to insert `\1` or `\\` or something else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`paste0`?

```
> string <- "667778767643555099889890"
> paste0("\\1", string)
[1] "\\1667778767643555099889890"
```